# Can you identify the difference between two links?

Tags: fonts

I made a goo.gl short link came on this odd event. This was the http://goo.gl/luliwG
generated but it is not the real http://goo.gl/luIiwG .

Thought this is interesting. I wonder why this font is popularly used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://goo.gl/luliwG` <-> `http://goo.gl/luIiwG` gives us the answer. One is a `l`, the other an `I`.